# How do I port my menu system to devices with no physical menu button e.g. Nexus?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

So I realised I've wasted a lot of time building a menu system that depends on a device with a physical menu button, which works great on all devices bar Nexus.

Right, so given that I've been using the typical `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu), onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) and onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`  methods. With the usual XML layout for a menu, as you do. How does one transition to a device that has no menu button?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [ActionBarSherlock.](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) It's backwards-compatible with older versions of Android, and the "action bar" is where you'll want to put your menu or commonly used options.